# Iterating through strings inside a list

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I iterate through strings inside a list, so that I can add specific values into a dictionary? For example, with the given list, I would like to set the prices for each item to be the dictionary keys and their respective items to be values.

**Given:**

```
list = ["10.99,cheese pizza", "4.99,vanilla milkshake", "4.99,chocolate milkshake"]
```

**Output (given an empty dictionary):**

```
{"10.99": ["cheese pizza"], "4.99": ["vanilla milkshake", "chocolate milkshake"]}
```

**Here is my attempt:**

```
list = ["10.99,cheese pizza", "4.99,vanilla milkshake", "4.99,chocolate milkshake"]

list = str(list)[1:-1].split(",")
listofitems = {}

ctr = 0
while ctr < len(list):
    listofitems[list[0]] = str(list[ctr])
    print listofitems
    ctr = ctr + 1
```

**And my output is this:**

```
{"'10.99": "'10.99"}
{"'10.99": "cheese pizza'"}
{"'10.99": " '4.99"}
{"'10.99": "vanilla milkshake'"}
{"'10.99": " '4.99"}
{"'10.99": "chocolate milkshake'"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That would not be a valid dictionary. There can only be a single key in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you've got quite a few things muddled here, but you are close.

First, don't call things after python built-ins, like `list`.

I'll break my answer down line by line so you can get this:

1. `str` converts the list to a string and then you try spliting it. Instead keep the list as is, and use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) over it to split each string in the list. Also, by using `item.split(',',1)` the only forces us to only split once, which comes in hand if an item has a comma in - e.g `Ham, cheese & tomato pizza`.

   ```
   list = str(list)[1:-1].split(",") 
   items = [item.split(',',1) for item in items]
   ```
2. Use `for` loop, not a `while` as you know the list your will loop over. Plus since each item is a pair of items, we can even *unpack* them in the for loop:

   ```
   for price,item in items:
   ```
3. Use [`Dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to safely get either the item with that key, and a default if it doesn't exist:

   ```
   price_set = item_dict.get(price,[])
   ```

Here is my complete version:

```
items = ["10.99,cheese pizza", "4.99,vanilla milkshake", "4.99,chocolate milkshake"]

items = [item.split(',',1) for item in items]

item_dict = {}

for price,item in items:
    price_set = item_dict.get(price,[])
    item_dict[price] = price_set + [item]

print item_dict
```

This outputs:

```
{'10.99': ['cheese pizza'], '4.99': ['vanilla milkshake', 'chocolate milkshake']}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ["10.99,cheese pizza", "4.99,vanilla milkshake", "4.99,chocolate milkshake"]
d = {}
for e in l:
     k,v = e.split(",")
     if d.has_key(k):
        d[k] += [v]
     else:
        d[k] = [v]
```

Comment: `split()` already produces a `list`. You don't need another level of comprehension for it. Also, don't name it `dict`.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @TigerhawkT3, fixing it. Also upvoted your answer: really nice to get better ways to do this (still a n00b myself). :)


d = {key: value for (key, value) in [(k,v) for k,v in (x.split(",") for x in list)]}

Comment: @user244255 ah yes! I'll try that out :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more pythonic 2 liner involving dictionary composition.

```
l = ["10.99,cheese pizza", "4.99,vanilla milkshake", "4.99,chocolate milkshake"]

products = [item.split(',') for item in l]
output = {y[0]:[x[1] for x in products if x[0] == y[0]] for y in products}
```

It first splits and formats them into products, then groups by price into a dictionary.